# Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.1.0

if I place order from frontend of my magento store then it is working perfectly but if I create new order from magento backend I can't select any shipping methods because it's show me "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time" and because of this error I can not create order from magento backend.

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0.I have added "Webshopapps Matrix Rates" module.

So I hope someone have solution for this issue.

[image]

Comment: enable another shipping method and check that it will works or not?

Comment: @AmitBera I have enabled free shipping method but it also not working in admin but working in frontend.

Comment: Exactly my problem right now. Works in the front end, but cannot get delivey methods even if I already enabled FREE DELIVERY. So weirdddd..

Answer (score 0):

May be  *Webshopapps Matrix Rates module not enable  admin store*.

**For  check the module enable or not.**

Goto  `admin>System>Configuration` and Select Current scope  **(Current Configuration Scope)** is **Default Configuration**   and check below two configuration

- goto `Advanced>Advanced` and check **Webshopapps Matrix** module
  *enable  or not*
- Also, or goto `Sales>Sales>Shipping Methods` and check **Webshopapps
  Matrix** module's **Enabled** stetting   *enable  or not*. Note that
  ,**(Current Configuration Scope)** is **Default Configuration**.

If this is not work then your should check your select shipping country have any value at Webshopapps Matric table

Or Any 3rd party module  have disabling your all module for admin. you should debug those

Comment: I have disable all other module and from admin I have set free shipping method but now problem is when I go to admin and create new order and click on set shipping method so it's send request using Ajax and after that it's show me "500 Internal Server Error" in ajax call.
do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I have add image for your better understaing please check and if you have any idea let me know.

Comment: Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Comment: Default FEDEX,DHL,UPS support only weight in KG, But webshopapps metrix rate is grams. How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?